# Pegar item específico de um fetchAll em PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

estou usando o código:

```
$lista = $db->query('select * from tabela') or trigger_error($db->error);
$lista->execute();
$item = $lista->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$mes = 1;
    while ($mes < 13){
    echo $obito[$mes]['total']; //quero listar o total aqui
    $mes++;
}
```

Comment: Olá Italo esse $db é uma instância do PDO??

Comment: o que é `$db`? o que é `queryMes`? falta código antes dessas linhas.

Comment: é uma instancia pdo sim

Comment: Pode ser `echo $item[3]['nome'];`

Comment: @VirgilioNovic a query funciona bem, é que eu simplifiquei o código acima. a variável $item deve listar todos os meus itens

Comment: @ItaloRodrigo não simplifique, coloque, realmente o que você esteja fazendo, tudo que for relevante e nos detalhes.

Comment: irei editar a pergunta

Comment: use o `print_r` ou  `var_dump` pra saber se vem como array ou objeto. Se é uma instância PDO, deve vir como objeto.

Comment: editei e postei o código que estou usando agora

Comment: Aquele `$lista->execute()` não faz mto sentido. Da um `print_r($obito)` e colque na pergunta, assim todo mundo sabe a estrutura dele.

Comment: obrigado a todos, consegui resolver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar o código abaixo;

```
$host = 'localhost'; // endereço do servidor de banco de dados.
$dbname = 'seu_banco_de_dados'; //nome de sua base de dados
$user   = 'root'; // seu usuário do banco
$pass   = ''; // sua senha do banco

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname,$user,$pass);
$lista = $db->prepare(queryMes($ano,$ibge));
$lista->execute();
$item = $lista->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo $item[3]['nome'];
```

> Ou pode usar o for para listar...

```
$host = 'localhost'; // endereço do servidor de banco de dados.
$dbname = 'seu_banco_de_dados'; //nome de sua base de dados
$user   = 'root'; // seu usuário do banco
$pass   = ''; // sua senha do banco
$lista = $db->prepare(queryMes($ano,$ibge));
$lista->execute();
$item = $lista->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($item as $info) {
    echo $info['nome']."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: na linha $obitos->execute(); dá erro Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::execute()

Comment: Ah ítalo você não esta usando o PDO?

Comment: editei e botei o código que estou usando agora, por favor dá uma olhada

Comment: Corrigi a resposta, altere os valores para os dados do seu banco de dados.

Comment: funcionou sim, obrigado. voce pode me explicar a diferença entre: $db = new mysqli(); e $db = new PDO();

Comment: são objetos diferentes. só conferir no manual. [PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) e [MySQLi Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli.php)

Comment: sem querer abusar da sua boa vontade, só falta mais um detalhe pra eu concluir o trabalho. como saber se $item[$i] existe?

Comment: sim coloque if(isset($item[$i]) { echo 'Existe';   }